# C pointer to a const and non-const types pointers

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I would like to declare a pointer that will point to pointers, where some of those pointers will be `const` and others will be a non-const pointers.

Below is a toy example. I have a set of `columns`. Each column is a pointer to a data of types `int` or `double`. So far this works fine. I would like to use `const` pointers as well.

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define TYPE_INT 0
#define TYPE_DOUBLE 1

int main(void) {
  int ncol = 2;
  int nrow = 3;
  void **columns = malloc(ncol*sizeof(void*));
  int *types = malloc(ncol*sizeof(int));
  columns[0] = malloc(nrow*sizeof(int));
  types[0] = TYPE_INT;
  columns[1] = malloc(nrow*sizeof(double));
  types[1] = TYPE_DOUBLE;
  for (int i=0; i<ncol; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j<nrow; ++j) {
      printf("value of column %d and row %d is: ", i+1, j+1);
      types[i]==TYPE_INT ?
        printf("%d", ((int*)columns[i])[j]) :
        printf("%.3f", ((double*)columns[i])[j]);
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

```
value of column 1 and row 1 is: 0
value of column 1 and row 2 is: 0
value of column 1 and row 3 is: 0
value of column 2 and row 1 is: 0.000
value of column 2 and row 2 is: 0.000
value of column 2 and row 3 is: 0.000
```

If I try to change `double *` to `const double*`

```
int main(void) {
  int ncol = 2;
  int nrow = 3;
  void **columns = malloc(ncol*sizeof(void*));
  int *types = malloc(ncol*sizeof(int));
  columns[0] = malloc(nrow*sizeof(int));
  types[0] = TYPE_INT;
  columns[1] = (const double*)malloc(nrow*sizeof(double));
  types[1] = TYPE_DOUBLE;
  for (int i=0; i<ncol; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j<nrow; ++j) {
      printf("value of column %d and row %d is: ", i+1, j+1);
      types[i]==TYPE_INT ?
        printf("%d", ((int*)columns[i])[j]) :
        printf("%.3f", ((const double*)columns[i])[j]);
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

then `gcc` warns

```
ptrs.c: In function ‘main’:
ptrs.c:13:14: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
   columns[1] = (const double*)malloc(nrow*sizeof(double));
```

How can I keep my columns pointers together, no matter if they are `const` or normal?

Comment: Get rid of the cast of the return value from `malloc`.  If you really want to retain it, then the correct type is `void *`, not `const double *`.  It's being converted to `void *` anyway, since `columns` is declared `void **`.  If you want to have type checking, then get rid of the `void` and use a `union` instead, handing each needed pointer type explicitly.

Comment: The problem is that pointers are coming from another software, so I cannot chose to not have type checking. `union` approach seems promissing, @TomKarzes would you mind to provide a working example as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your arrays (`columns` and `types`) being indexed by the same [column] index, I infer that a given row must be of the same type?

You have [essentially] a dynamic 2D "sparse" array.

Rather than using double star pointers (e.g. `void **`), I'd create a few structs for expansion.

This may be a bit of overdesign but here's my take on it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {
    TYPE_INT,
    TYPE_DOUBLE,
    TYPE_CONST_INT,
    TYPE_CONST_DOUBLE,
} type_t;

typedef union {
    void *vp;
    const void *vpc;

    int *ip;
    const int *ipc;

    double *dp;
    const double *dpc;
} rowptr_t;

typedef struct {
    int type;
    rowptr_t *rowptr;
} column_t;

typedef struct {
    int mat_ncol;
    int mat_nrow;
    column_t *mat_base;
} matrix_t;

size_t
typesize(type_t type)
{
    size_t siz;

    siz = 0;

    switch (type) {
    case TYPE_INT:
    case TYPE_CONST_INT:
        siz = 4;
        break;

    case TYPE_DOUBLE:
    case TYPE_CONST_DOUBLE:
        siz = 8;
        break;
    }

    return siz;
}

const char *
typefmt(type_t type)
{
    const char *fmt;

    fmt = NULL;

    switch (type) {
    case TYPE_INT:
    case TYPE_CONST_INT:
        fmt = "%d";
        break;

    case TYPE_DOUBLE:
    case TYPE_CONST_DOUBLE:
        fmt = "%Lf";
        break;
    }

    return fmt;
}

void
typeprt(matrix_t *mat,int colidx,int rowidx)
{
    column_t *col;
    rowptr_t *row;
    const void *vpc;

    col = &mat->mat_base[colidx];
    row = &col->rowptr[rowidx];

    vpc = row->vpc;

    switch (col->type) {
    case TYPE_INT:
    case TYPE_CONST_INT:
        printf("%d",*(const int *) vpc);
        break;

    case TYPE_DOUBLE:
    case TYPE_CONST_DOUBLE:
        printf("%.3f",*(const double *) vpc);
        break;
    }
}

void
matinit(matrix_t *mat,int ncol,int nrow)
{

    mat->mat_nrow = nrow;
    mat->mat_ncol = ncol;

    mat->mat_base = calloc(ncol,sizeof(*mat->mat_base));
}

void
allocrow(matrix_t *mat,int colidx,type_t type)
{
    column_t *col;
    size_t siz;

    siz = typesize(type);

    col = &mat->mat_base[colidx];
    col->rowptr = malloc(mat->mat_nrow * siz);
    col->type = type;
}

int
main(void)
{
    matrix_t mat;

    matinit(&mat,2,3);
    allocrow(&mat,0,TYPE_INT);
    allocrow(&mat,1,TYPE_DOUBLE);

    for (int i = 0; i < mat.mat_ncol; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.mat_nrow; ++j) {
            printf("value of column %d and row %d is: ", i + 1, j + 1);
            typeprt(&mat,i,j);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but during assignment you need to explicitly cast a `const` pointer to a non-const one. Also add additional `#define`s for `const` types, so that you know what is stored in the particular column:

```
#define TYPE_CONST_DOUBLE 2;

//...

//a const pointer storing an address of some buffer
const double *ptr = (const double*)malloc(nrow*sizeof(double));

//now we cast the const pointer to a non-const one and put it into the columns array
columns[1] = (void*)ptr;
types[1] = TYPE_CONST_DOUBLE;
```

And when you read the value from `columns[n]`, just cast back to the `const double *` if the type is `TYPE_CONST_DOUBLE`.

Comment: You should not cast the return value from `malloc`.

Comment: @jwdonahue yeah - just a copy-paste. But for the sake of the example it doesn't really matter – the important part is the next cast: `(void*)ptr`. And it's really not that "you **shouldn't** cast the retun value from `malloc`" but "you **don't have to**", because the cast is implicit in this particular case.